# should you convert strings to float when training for classification?

Tags: python, csv, scikit-learn, deep-learning, sklearn-pandas

I am working on a deep learning classification code. I have two classes and each class samples are stored in a CSV file. when I start my code, I read those files:

```
file_full=pd.read_csv("FULL.csv")
```

However, when I try to build the model :

```
model = Sequential()

# Add an input layer 
model.add(Dense(12, activation='relu', input_shape=(11,)))
```

I get this error:
**ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-0.0041958.1'**
does converting my list from strings to floats fixes this? and If so do I do it right before:

```
model = Sequential()
```

or in the beginning right after reading the file so I can run:

```
scaler = StandardScaler().fit(train)
```

to set the standard the data as a float?

Comment: Your example `ValueError` contains a string with two decimal dots (0.123.4), for which the automatic conversion - correctly - fails. You probably need to fix your file, or the way you read it (i.e. the call to `read_csv`)

Comment: yes, I removed  and it works. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to answer with so few info, but I am going to assume you're training a deep learning classifier on a CSV of extracted features.

Features have to be numerical, ie in python `int` or `float` type. Therefore when you try to load your data, `Keras` is trying to convert your data into a type he can process. The problem comes from the fact that your value `-0.0041958.1` has 2 `.` characters and thus can't be converted to a float. Maybe check your values and fix such errors.

Finally, we usually process the data just after loading it and separatly from the building of the model.

Comment: yes thank. I agree I removed the decimal and it worked.